# Are there any armor and weapon changes for the main characters?

Tags: conception-2

I'm playing Conception 2 and I noticed that I haven't changed my main character or any of the heroine's armor or weaponry... pretty much ever (except when I got the free armor and weapon DLC, but... I mean, does that count?). One of my heroines is pathetically weak in comparison to the others as far as attack power is concerned, so I was hoping to balancing it out with a weapon... but I can't buy weapons in the store and she doesn't seem to have any new armor sets either. I thought that I needed to get the armor from Ruby or Mark in R&D, but the labs don't have quests that give the girls armor. The lab did give me new armor, but it's crappy in comparison to the DLC one. I've never gotten a new set of armor for any of the girls.

I was wondering if I was just completely missing some element of the game that allowed them to change weapons? I do all the quests for the lab and guild and I have all of the heroines, plus I am at the end of the fourth labyrinth. Is there just never a change to weaponry and armor in the game? Or is there something I need to do to get them new weaponry/armor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you didn't miss anything, they upgrades are rare but they are out there. I'm at "stage 4" and only have one upgrade for each heroines weapons (the "S" versions) which I've just picked up from grinding dungeons over and over while levelling up batches of Star Children before I make them independent. Same with all but one with the armour. The only thing that seems to get steady upgrading is the main character's swords and armour.

I think Reflector armour does eventually become available in the store after it reaches Max level though. Also, after each dungeon, I just go to into the Item Edit and pick Team Best which shuffles weapon assignments to make sure everyone is using optimal build outs from what you've collected. (Be sure to unequip weapons and armour from Star Children before you Independent them though).

For what it's worth, the power on the girls comes from levelling them up and improving their magic attacks. Just rotate though each girl as you go on grind runs with the Star Children. All of my heroines are currently at around 22nd level.

Answer (score 1):

There are Quests that have a Upgrade Part ...
If you complete these you automatically get the new weapons for the heroines.

There are also some quests that need you to give a good Hero armor (that you cannot buy)
in exchange for a Heroine armor.  Once you did this, it seems that you can buy that armor then.  (I'm only on Chapter 3 and I got the type S weapons and the Reflector armor.)

It is possible that you need to level the city enough to get access to the required quests.

Answer (score 0):

You get the girls weapon and armor upgrades from doing quests in the lab. Each quest you complete unlocks another piece, for purchase, at the shop.

However, if your shop is capped out, you can't buy the ones you have not completed. If they do become available, later on, it is somewhere after town level 50+.

You don't need to worry about un-equipping you star children's equipment, as they will do it automatically, when you make them independent.